# Can I use hsqldb when I have queries written for my SQL-Server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am assigned to write the unit test cases for the Query classes (the class that interacts with the db). These classes are calling the .sql script files which I have to run on my in-memory db.

These .sql script files have Microsoft SQL Server functions (like `FIRST_VALUE()`) or another case where an insert query and a select query with the function `scopeIndex()` that returns me the newly generated primary key.

Example of the script files is given below. These two cases are throwing me an error when I try to run them on my HSQLDB (in memory db). Any suggestions how I could overcome this challenge? Are there any other in memory db that would not give me this problem?

UserDetailsSequenceId is auto generated.

```
INSERT INTO UserDetails( UserLogin,UserName,UserPassword)
VALUES(?, ?, ?)

Select DISTINCT Scope_Identity() as UserDetailsSequenceId from UserDetails
```

Comment: This is a complex and broad question. You may want to consider using something like [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mssqlserver/) instead. In general you will not be able to make this work except by using your real target database.

Comment: No.  You should _always_ use the _same_ database in your test and production stack.  Not doing so will open a large can of worms.  Any reason why you can't do your integration tests also with SQL Server?

Comment: Also, `FIRST_VALUE` is not SQL Server specific. It is a SQL standard window function.

Comment: Why don't you use a docker container with SQL Server for automated testing? You can also use VM snapshots (they are a little bit heavier).

Comment: I am not sure but I think compatable mode is not there in hsqldb.. while in h2db i can create and mention which type of db I need...like mysql or mssql. This works for First_Value() not for scope identity.